# Spring security requests authorization

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am new to spring security and was checking how to authorize requests to URLs in my application.

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authorize-requests), we add authorization as follow:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup", "/about").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        // ...
        .formLogin();
}
```

As this method worked fine for me, I was wondering if there's another dynamic way to specify this configuration. By using some sort of annotations for our REST controllers for example?

I have a solution in mind that would be really practical, but I wanted to make sure that there's no other way to do this before starting to develop my own code.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is an annotations as `@Secured/@PreAuthorize/@PostAuthorize`. this annotations are preferred way for applying method-level security, and supports Spring Expression Language out of the box, and provide expression-based access control.

for e.g

`@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
  public String yourControllerMethod() {
    return response;
}`

for detail check [here.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html)

Answer (score 1):

The only other way is to use the @Secured/@PreAuthorize/@PostAuthorize annotations. But you must put them on all webservices you want to secure.

Usually, when I build a webservices application, I like to authorize all requests on the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, and then secure requests one by one with these annotations.